# ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the path

Tags: git, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I was trying to install some framework packages using bower into my angularjs app. and i was getting this error using the command line tool:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to execute your command using Git Shell tool which is a Git aware powershell tool to run all git dependent technologies such as: **node, git and npm**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Git Bash instead of node.js or command prompt

As an Example for installing the ReactJS package, after opening Git Bash, execute the following command to install react:

```
bower install --save react
```

To install any other package you would essentially execute the following command:

```
bower install <package>
```